# Why this json swap code does not work?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this fun :

```
swapjson = function (j1,j2) 
{ var jj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(j1));
  j1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(j2));
  j2 = jj;  
}
```

I have also:

```
var myjson1 = {'x':1000, 'y':1000};
var myjson2 = {'x':2000, 'y':-2000};

swapjson (myjson1,myjson2);
console.log myjson1.x

1000 ?????
```

And I discover that inside the swapjson function the swap is made but not after call.

What is happen ? I dont understand what I'm doing bad... 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't have JSON, you have objects, but you're parsing them to JSON and back to avoid having copies of references, which seems like it's not a very good idea.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't replace the entire object like that, as the object itself isn't passed by referenced.
You can however change properties of the object passed, and it will stick, as a copy of the object is passed in.

So instead of parsing to strings and back to objects you can just iterate over the two objects keys, and replace one by one

```
swapjson = function (j1, j2) {
    var temp = {};

    for (key in j1) {
        temp[key] = j1[key];
        delete(j1[key]);
    }
    for (key in j2) {
        j1[key] = j2[key];
        delete(j2[key]);
    }

    for (key in temp) {
        j2[key] = temp[key];
    }

}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fqf4vtck/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You copy the *value* of `myjson1` (which is a reference to an object and nothing to do with JSON) into `j1`, and the *value* of `myjson2` into `j2`.

Then you overwrite the value of `j1` and the value of `j2`.

You never change the values of `myjson1` or `myjson2`.